# What is best practice when creating read-only DAOs for testing?

Tags: integration-testing, agile, dao, methodology, readonly

As part of the project I'm working we have a read-only DAO (a Bill class). The project itself should never create a new instance of Bill that isn't already represented in the database and should never change or update the values of this Bill class. So to prevent accidental modification of a Bill instance all constructors and private and there are no setters (Hibernate is used marshal the bill data from the database into the Bill instances and is not bothered by a lack of public constructors and setters).

Now to the question:

> As part of integration testing I need to violate the principle that our project will never 
>   create new bill objects not represented in the database. What is the best way to violate 
>   this principle for, and only for, the purposes of testing?

**Reflection-based Builder:** One idea I've proposed is to use a reflection-based builder so that the code of the Bill class need not change, and to have the builder fully tested in case any assumptions that the builder makes about fields of the Bill class are wrong are quickly identified.

**Package-private Constructor:** An alternative proposed by my boss is to include a package-private constructor that the builder can use. This has the advantage of being simpler and needs less testing to be assured that the builder works. However, it requires explicit code in the main code base to accommodate it.

Neither of us are very keen on either idea. So I was wondering if anyone else has had to deal with a similar problem before and how they dealt with it. I've been thumbing through "Agile Testing: A Practical Guide for Testers and Agile Teams", but haven't found any relevant so far.

NB. It's not as simple as interacting with the database directly as bills are part of a complex hierarchy of DAOs (including foreign key constraints in the database). So builders that can quickly and simply create such hierarchies and then persist all this data into the database are desirable.

Comment: As a side-note, since you are concerned about "accidental modification", you should be aware of `@Immutable`: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-entity

Answer (score 1):

Can you create a `MutableBill` class that is kept in your test source tree and is mapped to the same table as your `Bill` class?

Then your test code could populate the DB (for example [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/)) at the beginning of the test run using `MutableBill` and the rest of your code could continue using the immutable `Bill`.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to choose between those two, I'd go with the default visibility constructor. Reflection based programming creates hard-to-understand and not at all straightforward code. Your IDE's find references won't work properly, so someone might think that they face dead code. Then it turns out at runtime that the whole thing's broken.

Such additions (as package private things) are acceptable, because thorough testing is more desirable.